# How to do console debug ouput in a Lift web service?

Tags: debugging, scala, lift, sbt

I am developing a REST web service with Lift using SBT and jetty-run to build and run it. How do I output a string to SBT console from the code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Lift Logger:

https://github.com/dpp/liftweb/wiki/Logging-in-Lift

Or in fact any other logger you want... you can even use "println", output should be shown in SBT console.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that simply `System.err.println(String)` does the job. Maybe some threading issues can hide there, but it works for me.

Comment: It's what I meant by "println" in my answer

Comment: Ok. I've just didn't got it that time. Had to dig into Jetty source code to figure this out :-)